# Webform - Replace Form title with Node title

Tags: nodes, entities, webforms

I'm working on a Job Portal where-in i created a **content-type** for job listing and a Job Application **Webform**. I need to provide a link on the job node which will be linked to the webform and upon submission,the title of job listing node will be sent as the webform title(Editable or uneditable). And in the **Webform listing**, the form should have the **title** as that of the Job node from which it is applied.

I like to know, what are the ways with which this can be achieved

Answer (score 1):

In CCK there is a module called Field Reference. Enable that an you can create a field reference field, which you can link to a specific field in another node.